# check if element got scrolled to top

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, scrollto

I want to check if an element is scrolled to top with an offset of ~ 100px.

I´ve got a page with 5 subcontents and 2 classes to make backgrounds. It looks like this:

```
<div class="background1">
Content1
</div>
<div class="background2">
Content2
</div>
<div class="background1">
Content3
</div>
<div class="background2">
Content4
</div>
<div class="background1">
Content5
</div>
```

Now i want to check, when one of these classes reaches the top by scrolling

This is one of my last trys:

```
$('.background1', '.background2').position(function(){
             if($(this).position().top == 100){
            alert('checkThis');
        }
        });
```

I think this is my closest try by now...of course this code is in document.ready and at the end of my code....

TLDR: How to check if an element got scrolled to top (and some offset)?

Comment: window onscroll event seems to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have to listen for the scroll event, then check each element against the currently scrolled distance, something like :

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('.background1, .background2').each(function() {
        var topDistance = $(this).offset().top;

        if ( (topDistance+100) < scrollTop ) {
            alert( $(this).text() + ' was scrolled to the top' );
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This lloks about what i searched for...I totally fixed on that how to get the position...but forgot the scroll to get there...thanks! Accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: `position()` gets the elements position relative to the parent, I'm betting you're looking for `offset()`, which gets the position relative to the document. Also note the selector, as your selector looks for `.background1` inside `.background2`, and does not select both.

Comment: Awesome! This line:

`var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();`

was exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't figure out why the .offset().top value wasn't changing at all. Now I see that the offset value is related to document, so it's permanent -- that's why you need to compare it to the `$(window).scrollTop()` value.