# How to use scroll to top function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make an effect when mouse scrolls to a particular position?

```
<div id="target">
  <!-- some data here -->
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var target = $('#target');

if(target.scrollTop() > 10){
  alert('');
}
```

Comment: What do you think `target.height('10px')` does?

Comment: just edited my question please check

Comment: Do you mean when the mouse scrolls or when the window scrolls?

Comment: Where is your js code placed ? if you want to do something when an element is scrolled, you need to use the scroll event : `$(window).scroll(function() {
  console.log("scrolled");
});`

Comment: when the windows scrolls to target

Comment: maybe you can use some existing plugin  e.g. https://github.com/Mottie/visualNav

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if element got scrolled to top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961151/check-if-element-got-scrolled-to-top)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code inside 
   `$(window).on('scroll', function(){});` which will fire each time the window is scrolled like this:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
    var target = $('#target');
    if(target.scrollTop() > 10){
    console.log("Scrolled 10px");
    alert('');
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to select the entire HTML document for the scroll function, instead of just one specific div

jQuery

```
$(document).scroll(function(){  
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10){
      // if the current scroll of the window is greater than 10px
    alert('');
}
});
```